# Mock Lambda.invoke wrapped but not being called

Tags: aws-lambda, mocking, es6-promise, sinon, aws-sdk-mock

I'm having an issue while trying to mock `lambda.invoke` which I'm calling from within another lambda function.

- The function is wrapped (I can't use sinon after, it will tell me it's already wrapped).
- The test keeps calling the lambda function on AWS instead of calling the mock.
- It does the same if I use sinon instead of aws-sdk-mock.

`test.js`

```js
const { handler1 } = require('../handler');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const AWSMock = require('aws-sdk-mock');

describe('invoke', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    invokeMock = jest.fn();
    AWSMock.mock('Lambda', 'invoke', invokeMock);
    // const mLambda = { invoke: sinon.stub().returnsThis(), promise: sinon.stub() };
    // sinon.stub(AWS, 'Lambda').callsFake(() => mLambda);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    AWSMock.restore();
    sinon.restore();
  });

  test('test1', async () => {
    const event = { test: 'ok'};
    const handler = await handler1(event);
    expect(handler.statusCode).toBe(204);
  });
});
```

and my lambda function is:

`handler.js`

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

module.exports.handler1 = (event) => {
  // The initialisation bellow has to be in the handler not outside.
  const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    region: 'us-west-2' //change to your region
  });
  let params = {
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    LogType: 'Tail',
    FunctionName: 'handler2', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
    Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    lambda.invoke(params, function(error, data) {
      if(error) return reject(error);
      const payload = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
      if(!payload.success){
        return resolve({ statusCode: 400});
      }
      return resolve({ statusCode: 204});
    });
  });
};
```

EDIT: So the issue I had was because I had my lambda initialisation (`const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({})`) outside the handler instead on inside. Thanks to stijndepestel's answer.

Comment: How did you initialize `lambda` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from the code you have shared, but presumably, you have a reference to `lambda` in your `handler.js` before you have wrapped the function in your test. Could you add the `const lambda = new AWS.Lamda({})` line inside your handler function instead of outside of it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've just updated the code in the question, or if my assumption was correct and your problem is now solved.